# How do I make sure .mp3 files open with Windows Media Player in Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a program that needs to open a file in Windows Media Player because after the file is finished, it needs to kill wmplayer.exe. I've tried using `subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe", my_file])` and `subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe", my_file])` but this just opens Windows Media Player; not the specific file I want to open. (The my_file variable stores the path to the .mp3 file (it's in the same folder as the .py file) and works everywhere else I use it in the code and when I use `webbrowser.open`).

Full code:

```
try:

    import webbrowser
    import os
    import time
    import sys
    import getpass
    import pip
    import subprocess
    from contextlib import contextmanager

    @contextmanager
    def suppress_stdout():
        with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
            old_stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = devnull
            try:  
                yield
            finally:
                sys.stdout = old_stdout

    with suppress_stdout():
        pkgs = ['mutagen', 'gTTS']
        for package in pkgs:
            if package not in pip.get_installed_distributions():
                pip.main(['install', package])

    from gtts import gTTS
    from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

    my_file = "Text To Speech.mp3"

    username = getpass.getuser()

    def check_and_remove_file():
        if os.path.isfile(my_file):
            os.remove(my_file)

    def input_for_tts(message):
        tts = gTTS(text = input(message))
        tts.save('Text To Speech.mp3')
        subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe", my_file])

    check_and_remove_file()

    input_for_tts("""Hello there """ + username + """. This program is
used to output the user's input as speech.
Please input something for the program to say: """)

    def text_to_speech():
        while True:
            audio = MP3(my_file)
            audio_length = audio.info.length
            time.sleep((audio_length) + 0.25)
            os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM wmplayer.exe')
            time.sleep(0.5)

            while True:
                answer = input("""
Do you want to repeat? (Y/N) """).strip().lower()
                if answer in ["yes", "y"]:
                    input_for_tts("""
Please input something for the program to say: """)
                    return text_to_speech()
                elif answer in ["no", "n"]:
                    check_and_remove_file()
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print("""
Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again with either Y or N.""")

    text_to_speech()

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    check_and_remove_file()
    print("""
Goodbye!""")
    sys.exit()
```

Does anybody know how to make sure it will open that specific file with Windows Media Player, and not just Windows Media Player in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMP probably expects a full path to the media to play and doesn't care where your script is executing from. Try:

```
wmp = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
media_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(my_file))
subprocess.call([wmp, media_file])
```

Comment: Is `/Open` needed?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

if windows media player is set as your default player for .mp3 files calling

`os.startfile(path_to_your_mp3)`

should work.